# Changing Default Sort for Gitlab Issues

Tags: sorting, gitlab

Is there a way of changing the default sort in Gitlab issues tracker from "Newest" to "Recently Updated"?

I understand I can change it by just selecting the sort filter, however, doing this every time becomes annoying quickly.

Answer (score 4):

> does anyone know if there is a way of changing the default sort in Gitlab issues tracker from "Newest" to "Recently Updated"

Not that I know of (mid 2014):

- <del>there is [no issue in the GitLab CE project](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&issue_search=sort&state=opened&scope=all&assignee_id=&milestone_id=&label_id=)</del>
- the [one issue in GitHub GitLab project](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6785) (April 2014) refers to the GitLab CE project
- There [are a few suggestions](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general?query=sort%20issue), but none regarding the *default* sorting order
- there is nothing in the [main config `gitlab.yml` file](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/config/gitlab.yml.example)

That could be a good PR (Pull Request) to make, starting with:

- [`app/helpers/issues_helper.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/9879c427cef89a65d721133a62ff41a6e2a9057a/app/helpers/issues_helper.rb#L82-L85), which sorts issues by name
- [`app/models/project.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/9879c427cef89a65d721133a62ff41a6e2a9057a/app/models/project.rb#L281-L286), which also sorts issues by name
- [`app/views/projects/issues/_issue.html.haml`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/9879c427cef89a65d721133a62ff41a6e2a9057a/app/views/projects/issues/_issue.html.haml#L32-L34) which lists issues by name

---

Update January 2016: as mentioned by [stevenw00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501206/stevenw00) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772644/changing-default-sort-for-gitlab-issues/24772909?noredirect=1#comment57522912_24772909), there is now **[issue 5546](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/5546)**

> As a user frequently viewing a list of issues (or merge requests), I want to be able to have the list sort I use remembered, so that I do not have to constantly set the sort when ever I view a list of issues (or merge requests).

---

Update Dec. 2018 with [GitLab 11.6](https://about.gitlab.com/2018/12/22/gitlab-11-6-released/#per-user-saved-sort-order-in-issues-merge-requests-and-epics)

> ### Per-user saved sort order in issues, merge requests, and epics
>
> **There are now user-specified sort order selections in issues, merge requests, epics, and even roadmap views**.
> Which type of attribute you choose to sort by, and in which order you choose to sort (ascending or descending), is saved to the system, so that when you return to the same type of object list, it will remain what you have selected previously.

[image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/11_6/sort-order.png]

---

Update August 2019, GitLab 12.2

[Manual Issue List Sorting](https://about.gitlab.com/2019/08/22/gitlab-12-2-released/#manual-issue-list-sorting)

> As of 12.2, you can now sort an Issue List in Manual mode, which allows you to drag and drop Issues within the list to assign them a relative order.

[image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/12_2/manual-issue-sorting.gif]

> The order is persisted and maintained across the entire instance for all Project Issue Lists and Group Issue Lists that have Manual mode enabled

See [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/sorting_issue_lists.html#manual-sorting) and [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/62178).

---

With [GitLab 13.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/12/22/gitlab-13-7-released/#sort-issues-by-the-number-of-issues-they-are-blocking) (December 2020), you have a new (non-free) option:

> ### Sort issues by the number of issues they are blocking
>
> While prioritizing a list of issues in GitLab, it’s often important to determine the critical path and whether an issue is blocking other issues.
>
> With the current issue list, it is impossible to see which issues are blocking other issues. The only way to do so is to open each one and see the [list of blockers](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/2035) below the issue description, which is a very time-consuming task!
>
> As of 13.7, you can now use the filter for “Blocking” on any issue list, and you will see a list sorted by the number of blockers.
>
> https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_7/sort-issues-by-blockers.png -- Sort issues by the number of issues they are blocking
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/sorting_issue_lists.html#sorting-by-blocking-issues) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/34247).

Comment: Thanks mate, I was hoping I hadn't just missed something simple.
I will take a look at those files though and see what I can dig out.

Comment: There is a newer issue opened on Dec 29, 15. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/5546

Comment: @stevenw00 Thank you. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

So, I found a couple of things.

Modified the following file:
`app/controllers/projects/issues_controller.rb`

On line 29, change from:
`sort_param = params[:sort] || 'newest'`
Change to:
`sort_param = params[:sort] || 'recently_updated'`

Modified the following file:
`app/views/shared/_sort_dropdown.html.haml`

On line 7, change from:
`Newest`
Change to:
`Recently updated`

However, still have an issue, it now shows Recently updated as the default option in the menu, however, it doesn't actually apply the sort. They still sort by default as newest.

Any further opinions :S